# Finding the 5th root of a complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

QUESTION:
What is the 5th roots of $1 + 2i$?

ATTEMPT:
I've began by finding the modulus '$r$'.

$r^2= 1^2 + 2^2 = 5$. 
Therefore $r = \sqrt{5}$

Then I've tried to use $\tan^{-1}(\frac21) = \tan^{-1}(2)$, but this is where I got stuck.

Comment: Draw this number in the Argand plane.

Comment: Write the number as $re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 1):

Do not worry if you get stuck, just continue with you partial results.

Let us name $a=1+2i$. You have already computed the polar form $a=r e^{i\varphi}= r (\cos \varphi + i \cos \varphi)\;$ with $r=\sqrt{5}, \varphi = \arctan 2$.

As there are multiple 5th root of $a,\,$ I assume you want to compute the so-called principle 5th root 
$b = \sqrt[5] a = r^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{i\frac{\varphi}{5}}.$

Just insert your data for $a$ and get
$$b = \sqrt[5] a = r^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{i\frac{\varphi}{5}}=
5^\frac{1}{10}\Big(\cos(\frac{1}{5}\arctan 2) + i \sin(\frac{1}{5}\arctan 2)\Big)$$

If you like, you can compute the approximate  cartesian values

$$  \sqrt[5]{1+2i} \approx 1.14594 + 0.25798\cdot i$$

As you may already know, you can get all 5th complex roots of $1+2i$ as
$$
5^\frac{1}{10}\Big(\cos(\frac{1}{5}(2k\pi + \arctan 2)) + i \sin(\frac{1}{5}(2k\pi + \arctan 2))\Big),\quad 0\le k < 5$$

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated the modulus and argument of $1+2i$.
$$|1+2i|=5^{1/2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \arg{(1+2i)}=\tan^{-1}2$$ 
More generally though, the argument could be written as $\tan^{-1}2+2n\pi$, because adding on multiples of $2\pi$ doesn't change the angle.  Hence you have
$$
\begin{align}
z^5&=5^{1/2}e^{(\tan^{-1}2+2n\pi)i} \\
z&=5^{1/10}e^{(\tan^{-1}2+2n\pi)i/5} \\
\end{align}
$$

This will give you various different answers depending on the value of $n$.  You should find that there are 5 distinct answers, after which you'll just be repeating solutions with arguments offset by multiples of $2\pi$.